# How to resolve Build failed while publishing the asp.net Web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, build, publishing-site

I have a ASP.NET web application with MVC5 framework I want to make it live on the internet I have a domain, hosting and a FTP account on GoDaddy. I followed the tutorial on YouTube and successfully done the procedure on the server side.
But I am getting an error in publishing the app on my side.

I am using the visual studio 2017 and it's making some problems.
Here are some screenshots with the descriptions.

I've created the profile successfully in VS 17 and validate the connection. when I click on the publish button it gives this error.

[image: First encounter with the problem]

There is nothing wrong with the code. When I open this file, the error refers to, it shows no error.

After keeping the file open and again clicking the Publish button there are no errors just this warning.

[image: Warning]

You can see the Build failed message in bottom left-hand side corner.

It gives no error or warning while manually building or rebuilding the project.

[image: Building / Rebuilding of app]

It's My first attempt to upload the site on the live server and it's for learning purposes. So any help or Guiding will be a huge favor.

I can provide more information if needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just select the release option instead of debug while creating the profile.
It has it's own pros and cons but it will solve the problem for now.